# _this3.props.onHandlerStateChange is not a function. (In '_this3.props.onHandlerStateChange(e)', '_this3.props.onHandlerStateChange' is true)

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I'm using touchable opacity in my react-native application, Initially it's in disabled mode after 1 minute this will be enabled, But if I trigger this touchable opacity when its in disabled mode which throws an error

> _this3.props.onHandlerStateChange is not a function. (In '_this3.props.onHandlerStateChange(e)', '_this3.props.onHandlerStateChange' is true)

```
  <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.isResendDisabled} onPress={this.onResendOtp}>
    <Text>Resend Otp</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. make sure you are importing ToucahbleOpacity from react-native and not react-native-gesture-handler